# Loop through model and create textbox for each property, in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model with 5-6 properties. Rather than tediously writing a line of code to create a textbox in the view, is it possible to loop through all the properties in the model (which are public) and create a textbox in the view for each iteration?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use `@Html.EditorForModel()` or if you want more granular control you can generate the textboxes with the help of a little reflection:

```
@foreach (var property in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   @Html.Label(property.Name)
   @Html.TextBox(property.Name)
}
```

Comment: I believe this ignores all annotations of said property

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in feature for this.  @[Html.EditorForModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorformodel.aspx)() will spit out the appropriate editor controls for each field.  Read up on the "editor templates" feature in MVC to understand how this works, how to customize it, etc.